# RESTful web service to get random number verb

Tags: web-services, rest

If you create a RESTful web service that can return random numbers, what verb should you use?

My personal feeling is use POST, because you are creating a new random number each time, but I have heard some convincing arguments for using GET, since you are essentially getting random numbers.

GET also has the danger of being cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In REST, think resources.

If the service is just returning random numbers then you aren't really creating a new resource (e.g a new number generator), so GET feels appropriate.

[Fowler's article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) provides a good explanation on the subject.

Comment: I commented my question. Your answer is very much in line with the arguments I have heard for GET, but with GET you do have the danger of caching

Comment: Indeed. Using a GET without providing a unique parameter (maybe a seed, on this case?) would likely be cached.

Comment: Still, if you use the same seed you could end up with the same number. I'm playing devils advocate here, while reading through the article you posted. Also, you could think of the random numbers as resources, resources that you can only create and never update or query

Answer (score 1):

The theory behind random number generators says that the same random number algorithm with the same seed should produce the same sequence of random numbers every time. Consider a GET verb for N numbers with seed J.

If you use the same seed J every time you call this service with N = 1, you will get 1 number, exactly the same, every time.

If you use the same seed J every time you call this service with N = 50, you will get the same 50 numbers, every time.  I like this option as I can put an iterator around the result set to give me only 1 number when I ask for a random number (saving round trip calls), and I then have a sequence I can count on for testing. Caching is allowed/preferred in this situation.

If you want different numbers each time you call the service, pick a different seed J when you GET the numbers.  An oft-suggested seed is the current time and date, which changes a lot.

Since we are offering the ability to specify the seed, this service is still idempotent.