# When and where to aggregate or perform calculations on data in RESTful Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there is a general way one should go about aggregating data or performing calculations on it (e.g. grabbing ten random lines of a movie script, or multiplying ten product prices by each other) in Rails or in MVCs in general. Specifically I'm attempting to do the first example (10 lines of a movie script) in my application.

I'm using Rails 5.2+. What I've tried so far is making an instance method `getRandomLines` in my `ScriptLinesController`. But I'm not sure whether I should instead be using the show method and aggregating the data on the client-side, or if I should put the method in the model `ScriptLine`

I've tested the following route using Postman and it works, but it seems like the wrong way to go about it:

```rb
#My routes.rb:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get 'script_lines/test', to: 'script_lines#getRandomLines'

end
```

My controller looks like this:

```rb
class ScriptLinesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: ScriptLine.all
  end

  def show
    scriptLine = ScriptLine.find_by(id: params[:id])

    render json: scriptLine
  end

  def getRandomLines
    numLines=rand(0..9)
    nineLines = []
    numLines.times do
      id_num = rand(1..ScriptLine.last.id)
      nineLines << ScriptLine.find_by(id: id_num)
    end

    render json: nineLines[0]
  end
end
```

My model looks like this:

```rb
class ScriptLine < ApplicationRecord
  validates :line_number, presence:true

  belongs_to :script
end
```

Finally my schema looks like this:

```rb
  create_table "script_lines", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "line_number"
    t.string "line"
    t.bigint "script_id"
    t.index ["script_id"], name: "index_script_lines_on_script_id"
  end
```

So in sum, is creating methods in the controller and specifying routes to those methods the right way to aggregate/perform calculations on data in a RESTful manner? In particular I'm wondering if the 7 standard RESTful routes are the only routes allowed, or if you can have ad-hoc routes for manipulating data that comply with REST principles.

This is my first question, so apologies in advance if it's asking too much or too vague, will modify accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty broad design question so I'm just going to give a list of general pointers to think about:

- A major component of RESTful web service design is picking the right resources, which do not need to correspond directly with the tables in your database. It's totally appropriate to invent new resources (usually but now always with a corresponding class in `models/`) that map more naturally to what the client is looking for.
- In general I'd recommend performing aggregations on the server side at the database level (or via some other data-storage mechanism like a pre-computed cache if even the database is too slow)
- If you're using a relational database, it can be useful to define views that perform the aggregation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createview.html). Then you can create an activerecord model that references the view
- It's generally not worth creating controller methods that are named differently from what's in your routes file. In your example I'd just have a new action `random` at `/script_lines/random` and then a controller method `random`.
- Depending on how truly "RESTful" you want to be, you may or may not need be working in a codebase where it's acceptable to define non-standard controller actions and it might or might not be acceptable for a GET endpoint to return random results like this (both of these can break the strict definition of REST). Check out this answer: [RESTful web service to get random number verb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396167/restful-web-service-to-get-random-number-verb) for some more context.

Personally, if I wasn't overly concerned with RESTful-ness, I'd add a new action to the ScriptLinesController like this:

```
class ScriptLinesController < ApplicationController
  def random
    num_lines = rand(0..9)
    render json: ScriptLine.order("RANDOM()").limit(num_lines)
  end
end
```

As the `random` function got more complicated over time I'd consider moving it to the `ScriptLine` model. If even more complexity got added that was all logically related to the concept of "Collection of random script lines" I'd move that code out to a separate other model and create a new controller.

Comment: Hi, I upvoted this, thanks so much for all the advice. I realize now I didn't ask the most essential part of my question, whether your only routes should be the 7 standard restful "show", "index", "update" etc. routes in order for your API to be restful, or whether you can make ad hoc functions that correspond to the "principles of REST", whatever that might mean. I'll edit my question to do this and will accept your answer as solving if it answers that as well. 

Just another question as well, when you say "at the database level", does this mean manipulation with a controller method?

Comment: @A.Lelli by "at the database level" I mean like I did in my example. You still write code in the controller (or in the model called by the controller), but the actual selection or aggregation is done by the DB. In this case I'm using `order(RANDOM())` and `limit` together to do the picking of the random row in the DB instead of in ruby.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!